# Increase a value in lambda function

Tags: java, lambda

How do I increase a value in the following lambda expression?

```java
value -> value + (count++)
```

It is not working because the variable (`count`) has to be final.
Is there a workaround?

The code is just a project/test for the university, so nothing special.
The two java `for` loops are just for testing reasons.

Here's the code:

```java
@Test 
void testApplyToAllString() { 
    StapelMitArray<String> Stapel = new StapelMitArray(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { 
        Stapel.insert("String" + i);
    }
    int count = 1; 
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        count ++; 
        Stapel.applyToAll(wert -> wert.substring(0, count)); 
    }
    assertEquals("Strin", Stapel.remove());
    assertEquals("Stri", Stapel.remove());
    assertEquals("Str", Stapel.remove());
    assertEquals("St", Stapel.remove());
    assertEquals("S", Stapel.remove()); 
}
```

I tried this as well:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    final int count = a.length - i;
    Stapel.applyToAll(wert -> wert.substring(0, count));
}
```

It worked for the first of the following `assertEquals`:

```java
assertEquals("S", Stapel.remove());
assertEquals("St", Stapel.remove());
assertEquals("Str", Stapel.remove());
assertEquals("Stri", Stapel.remove());
assertEquals("Strin", Stapel.remove());
```

Answer (score 1):

Make [variable] `count` an array having one element.

```java
int[] count = new int[1]; // all array elements implicitly initialized to 0 (zero)
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    count[0]++; 
    Stapel.applyToAll(wert -> wert.substring(0, count[0])); 
}
```

Alternatively, use a "wrapper", for example [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

```java
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    Stapel.applyToAll(wert -> wert.substring(0, count.incrementAndGet())); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

All lambda function are immutable because they reference the passed parameter but do not modify the parameter's value to reach their result. However these expressions can use variables defined in an outer scope, local variables must be (effectively) final.

Luckily you can declare (and modify) multiple variables in for loop.

```java
@Test 
void testApplyToAllString() { 
    StapelMitArray<String> Stapel = new StapelMitArray(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { 
        Stapel.insert("String" + i);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0, count = 1; i < a.length; i++, count++) {
        Stapel.applyToAll(wert -> wert.substring(0,count)); 
    } 
    assertEquals("Strin", Stapel.remove());
    assertEquals("Stri", Stapel.remove());
    assertEquals("Str", Stapel.remove());
    assertEquals("St", Stapel.remove());
    assertEquals("S", Stapel.remove()); 
}
```

Because the `count` is always `i+1` it can simplify

```java
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    Stapel.applyToAll(wert -> wert.substring(0, i+1)); 
}
```